# Does convergence of polynomials imply that of its coefficients?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, convergence-divergence

Let $\{p_{n}\}$ be a sequence of polynomials and $f$ a continuous function
on $[0,1]$ such that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}|p_{n}(x)-f(x)|dx\to 0$.
Let $c_{n,k}$ be the coefficient of $x^{k}$ in $p_{n}(x)$. Can we conclude
that $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\lim }c_{n,k}$ exists for each $k$?.

What I know so far: if the degrees of $p_{n}^{\prime }s$ are bounded then
this is true. In fact, we can replace $L^{1}$ convergence by convergence in
any norm on $C[0,1]$; to see this we just have to note that for fixed $N$, $%
\sum_{k=0}^{N}c_{i}x^{i}\rightarrow (c_{0},c_{1},...,c_{N})$ is a
linear map on a finite-dimensional subspace and hence it is continuous. My
guess is that the result fails when there is no restriction on the degrees.
But if $p_{n}(z)$ converges uniformly in some disk around $0$ in the complex
plane then the conclusion holds. To construct a counterexample we have to
avoid this situation. Maybe there is a very simple example but I haven't been
to find one. Thank you for investing your time on this.

Comment: Hello! Could you please help me with my question on the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350386/prove-or-disprove-that-this-paramater-dependent-integral-is-continously-differen 
I know the question isn't related to yours, but could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Consider the sequence of polynomials

$$
p_n(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    (1-x)^n, & \text{if}\ n\equiv 0 \mod 2 \\
    x^n, & \text{if}\ n\equiv 1 \mod 2
  \end{array}\right.
$$

Then $p_n(x)$ converges to $0$ but the constant term is oscillating.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that teh conclusion fails even with uniform convergence. Consider $x(1-x)p_n(x)$ with the $p_n$' you have defined and look at the coefficient of $x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Or, use Ethan's sequence with the interval $[1/4, 3/4]$, on which it converges uniformly.

Comment: What if the polynomial converges to something other than $0$ though?

Comment: @Jam You can make it work if $f$ is any function that can be approximated by polynomials. Indeed, if $g_n$ is a sequence of polynomials converging to $f$, then we can assume $g_n(0)$ converges to $f(0)$ since otherwise we're done. But then $p_n+g_n$ still converges to $f$ while $p_n(0)+g_n(0)$ has two subsequences which converge to $f(0)$ and $f(0)+1$ respectively.