# Prove or disprove that this paramater-dependent integral is continously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

How to prove (or perhaps disprove) that the following statement is correct:

If $f: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continously differentiable, then $F(x) = \int_0^{\sqrt[3]{x}}t^3f(xt)dt$ is also continously differentiable on $(-1,1)$.

I know that if the upper bound of the integral was contionously differentiable, then $F$ would also be. But this is not the case here. I've tried proving this statement by definition of derivatives and finding a simple counterexample but without any luck.

Comment: What would be the derivative for $x \ne 0$? And what if you try to compute $F'(0)$ from the definition?

Comment: I know the formula for $x \neq 0$ and I tried exactly that, to compute $F'(0)$ by definition but failed to do so. I know the only problem is in $x = 0$ because only there the upper bound of the integral isn't continously differentiable.

Comment: Try to use the definition of the derivative for $x = 0$.